# Luminous Balloon

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Four times they proclaimed their name,
>   Spare the Romans and it was the same.
>
> Diverging, in a sacred abode they prayed,
>   Afterwards some real ideas they sprayed.
>
> Despite their fame, they stressed their existence
>   Before using doors in the wrong sense.
>
> For the next, they chose a tail for the title
>   Which was poetic for it was their final.

---

Can you guess who they are?

Comment: I have a feeling that this poem is describing things about the letters of the answer.

Comment: Congratulations on 6666 reputation. A notable achievement!

Comment: @Emrakul: :D Thanks. I was ruing the one downvote on this question last night. But I guess everything has a purpose. Wouldn't have hit exactly 6666 without that downvote. So in a truly rare event, I want to thank the downvoter for helping me achieve such a perfect figure. :P

Comment: Don't understand downvoting this - the clues are awesome!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are

> the rock band Led Zeppelin.  The clues point to the titles of their albums.

Four times they proclaimed their name,

> the first four albums are simply titled Led Zeppelin I, II, III and IV

Spare the Romans and it was the same.

> but for the number, each album has the same title (thanks to DasBeasto)

Diverging, in a sacred abode they prayed,

> Houses of the Holy

Afterwards some real ideas they sprayed.

> Physical Graffiti

Despite their fame, they stressed their existence

> Presence

Before using doors in the wrong sense.

> In Through the Out Door

For the next, they chose a tail for the title
Which was poetic for it was their final.

> Coda ("coda", meaning "tail" in Italian, is a musical term designating the closing section of a piece)

Luminous Balloon

> Luminous = L.E.D.  Balloon = Zeppelin :D

Comment: I don't get the title though. Why Luminous?

Comment: @SirParselot see my edit

Comment: Haha I thought of that right after I posted it.

Comment: The "spare the Romans" part is still about the first 4 album reference. The numbers on the albums were written in Roman Numerals and other than the numbers the albums were the same title. So spare the Romans (without the Roman numerals) it was the same.

Comment: @DasBeasto did IV actually have a title written with roman numerals? People _call_ it that, after the first three, but AIUI there was no actual title at all on the album itself.

Comment: Great job. Could you edit in the meaning of Coda, so my clue becomes clearer there? Apart from that, you've cracked it all perfectly, with @DasBeasto catching the Romans clue.

Comment: @CodeNewbie added the meaning of "coda"